# Stop lead conversion if Lead is > 40 days

Tags: validation

I have a requirement to stop lead conversions if the lead is > 40 days

I tried the below but it isn't working.

```
AND( ISPICKVAL( Status , 'Closed - Converted') , TODAY() - DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)> 40)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. When I put that formula (I changed the Status value)  in a Validation Rule for one of our custom objects, it works to prevent saving that record. I don't know much about Lead Conversion, but putting this Validation Rule on the Lead object would, I think, only allow the Lead record not to be saved. I am not sure that would prevent a Lead Conversion. On which object do you have this Validation Rule?

Comment: You need to use `IsConverted` instead of `Status` - see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130233/when-the-value-of-isconverted-gets-changed for more info

Comment: I came back to modify/update my Comment - I did verify in my sandbox that a Validation Rule on the Lead object will prevent Lead Conversion.  However, that was using only the date check part of the OP's formula.  I had not yet tried the Status check part. Thanks @identigral.

Comment: Check this knowledge article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331020&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I was able to solve this using the isconverted recommendation. Much appreciated!